# cakephp using components as controller methods

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, components

I'm trying to find the best, cleanest way of initialising a method from within another controller. I basically want to record 'likes', 'posts' etc as 'actions' when they happen.

Actions are working fine on submission, but not from outside it's own controller.

In the LikesController, I want to be able to simply go:

```
$this->Action->add($fields);
```

But this doesn't work, even if I do `$this->loadModel('Action');` beforehand. After reading around it seems that 'components' is the way to go...

So I was wondering how I would achieve this using components. I've got this so far in my LikesController:

```
public $components = array(
    'RequestHandler','Helper',
        'Action' => array('controller'=>'actions', 'action'=>'add'),
);
```

But still no joy when I try to call `$this->Action->add`.

What is the best method of doing this, and how can I set up the component class to work as though it is the Action controller, and able to use its methods?

If I can award REP to the best answer then I will..! Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A component isn't the same as a model. So if you want to do things this way, you'll have to turn your `Action` model into a Component.

The component would go into `Controller/Component/ActionComponent.php`, and then it can be included into your Controllers like this:

```
public $components = array(..., 'Action');
```

The logic in your Component can be similar to that in a Model, but there are some differences. For example, you could still have an Action model, and the component can use that for CRUD and other stuff. You'll have to use `ClassRegistry::init()` to load a model into your Component though.

I can't really explain how to do exactly what you want, one reason for that being that I don't know precisely enough what it is you do want.
However, I've written my own Component before and you can use it for reference if you like - it's possibly more complicated than yours so you can see how to write methods for it.

[Custom ACL Component](https://github.com/SharkofMirkwood/Cakephp-Custom-ACL-Component)

In that example, once it's included in a Controller, I can simply call `$this->CustomAcl->check()` anywhere I like.

I hope this is enough to get you started at least.

Comment: Thanks, that looks great although having gone through this I have been stuck at one hurdle and that's the initialization of the component. If you're able to help further I would be MUCH appreciated..!!!! http://pastebin.com/7CiFTByg

Comment: I have also tried line 10 with an underscore, i.e. `$this->_controller =& $controller;` but still the same error @SharkofMirkwood

Comment: Try `$this->_controller = $controller;`? In any case, you probably don't actually need to override the `initialise()` method - that was sort of specific to my app. Try getting rid of that part completely ;)

Comment: Also get rid of anything else you think might not be necessary - just put in what you need, and put anything back if it complains.