# cakephp how to log events

Tags: php, cakephp, methods, controllers

I want to log events across multiple controllers and store them in my 'actions' database. I need to have actions as a class/controller because I need to get the ID for that action object after it has saved.

What is the best way of doing this so that I can run a method across any controllers to add a new action into the database?

`$this->Action->log($array)`;

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a [Component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html) for that. Components are objects that can be used across any controller (as long as you include it in the controller's `$components` property, or in that of the AppController).

For example, if you have any experience with `Auth` in Cake, that's a Component, and its methods can be called from any controller.

More info about components here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html

If you need more help, feel free to try and write a component yourself and come back with any problems you might have.

Comment: I've had a go at this too - could you please see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967453/cakephp-using-components-as-controller-methods